# Add a link for every word in a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add an href for every word which is inside a webpage and then save it again with added href. To do it I'm using BeautifulSoup and this code is working fine:

```
wordToSearch = "war"
for text in soup2.find_all(text=True):
if re.search(r'(\w*)%s\b' %wordToSearch, text):
    text.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(re.sub(r'(\w*)%s\b' % wordToSearch, r'<a href="http://example.com/%s">%s</a>' %(wordToSearch, wordToSearch), text, re.UNICODE), 'html.parser'))
```

And then I write the new file with this code:

```
with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

This is working fine only if I need to add href to a single specific word, but I don't know how to do it if I want to add href for a list of words:

```
listOfWords = ["war", "love"]

for text in soup2.find_all(text=True):
    for a in listOfWords:
        if re.search(r'(\w*)%s\b' %a, text):
            text.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(re.sub(r'(\w*)%s\b' %a, r'<a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/%s">%s</a>' %(a, a), text, re.UNICODE), 'html.parser'))
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 110, in <module>
    text.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(re.sub(r'(\w*)%s\b' % wordToSearch, r'<a href="http://example.com/%s">%s</a>' %(wordToSearch, wordToSearch), text, re.UNICODE), 'html.parser'))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 235, in replace_with
    "Cannot replace one element with another when the"
ValueError: Cannot replace one element with another when theelement to be replaced is not part of a tree
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to rebuild the soup after each pass.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<html>
<p>love blah blah war blah blah  love blah blah war</p>
<p>love blah blah  blah blah  love blah blah </p>
<p>blah blah love blah blah war blah blah  love blah blah war blah blah</p>
</html>

"""
listOfWords = ["war", "love"]
for a in listOfWords:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for text in soup.find_all(text=True):
        if re.search(r'(\w*)%s\b' %a, text):
            text.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(re.sub(r'(\w*)%s\b' %a, r'<a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/%s">%s</a>' %(a, a), text, re.UNICODE), 'html.parser'))
    html = str(soup)
print (soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
<p><a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/love">love</a> blah blah <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/war">war</a> blah blah  <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/love">love</a> blah blah <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/war">war</a></p>
<p><a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/love">love</a> blah blah  blah blah  <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/love">love</a> blah blah </p>
<p>blah blah <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/love">love</a> blah blah <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/war">war</a> blah blah  <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/love">love</a> blah blah <a href="https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/war">war</a> blah blah</p>
</html>
```